# How to perform a chi-squared test on tables with multiple dimensions?

Tags: r, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I want to test with the chi-squared test if there is a difference between the survival rate for each earthworm species and the flooding condition of my experiment. An example of my dataset, survival1, is:

[image]

The survival rate can be variable between 0, 0.33, 0.67, and 1. The earthworm species varies between L. rubellus and A. caliginosa. The flooding can be either Yes or No. Do you have any suggestions to use the chi-squared test on the different groups?

Comment: If you just want to compare the distribution of survival.rate between flooded and not flooded then you could use a chi-square test, what is your question?

Comment: You could carry out a chi-square test if you count survived and not survived and put those counts together with cross-combinations of predictors. The good news is that chi-square can be calculated so long as you have observed and expected frequencies. The bad news is that gets more difficult the more variables you are collapsing into a such a table. In short, this path is a statistical dead end as compared with modelling survival. perhaps as a logit model.

Comment: Why do you want to use chi-square for this?  Looks like a regression problem to me.

Comment: The question seems to imply that you looking at earthworms in threes, so that for each trio 0, 1, 2 or 3 survive out of 3. If so, that probably has implications for the data generation process.